# Bridge from QEMU inside WLS2 to Windows

Tags: networking, ping, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v, qemu

I have a Windows (Windows 10 Enterprise 20H2) network interface with static address 192.168.1.6 set.
In Hyper-V manager I set WSL virtual switch to connect to "External network" and choose interface mentioned above.

In WSL2 I have installed "Ubuntu 20.04".
After starting WSL2 I set up a bridge:

```
sudo ip link add br0 type bridge stp_state 0
sudo ip link set eth0 master br0
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.254/20 dev br0
sudo ip link set br0 up
```

I downloaded QEMU image from here: [https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/armhf/](https://people.debian.org/%7Eaurel32/qemu/armhf/) (standard version) and run it like this:

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -kernel /home/lesz/qemu/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-vexpress -initrd /home/lesz/qemu/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-vexpress -drive if=sd,file=/home/lesz/qemu/debian_wheezy_armhf_standard.qcow2 -append "root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 console=ttyAMA0" -nographic -m 1024 -net nic -net bridge,br=br0
```

When system is booted I log in as root and set static ip:

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.7/20 dev eth0
```

**On QEMU:**

```
root@debian-armhf:~# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:12:34:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.7/20 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@debian-armhf:~# ping 192.168.1.6
PING 192.168.1.6 (192.168.1.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.7 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.7 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.7 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.1.6 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3015ms
pipe 3

root@debian-armhf:~# ping 192.168.1.254
PING 192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=3.83 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.592 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.380 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.254 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.380/1.601/3.831/1.579 ms
```

**On Ubuntu (WSL2)**

```
ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ce:d0:ba:27:16:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:bf:b8:9e:48:29 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:ae:f5:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
12: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:ae:f5:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.254/20 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:feae:f5a6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
37: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:d4:42:b8:cd:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fcd4:42ff:feb8:cddd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ip route
192.168.0.0/20 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.254

cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

ping 192.168.1.6
PING 192.168.1.6 (192.168.1.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.316 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.6: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.308 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.6: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.350 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.6 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2115ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.308/0.324/0.350/0.018 ms

ping 192.168.1.7
PING 192.168.1.7 (192.168.1.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.7: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.884 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.7: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.557 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.7: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.457 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.7 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2058ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.457/0.632/0.884/0.182 ms
```

**On Windows:**

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::15d3:b518:25fa:e782%24
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.6
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

PS C:\> ping 192.168.1.7

Pinging 192.168.1.7 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.6: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.7:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 1, Lost = 2 (66% loss),
Control-C

PS C:\> ping 192.168.1.254

Pinging 192.168.1.254 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.254:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
Control-C
```

Additional info:
It seem that traffic is blocked in one direction only - i.e. QEMU answers ARP Request but ARP Reply doesn't reach physical interface on Windows (at the same time ARP Request from QEMU is not being answered at all):
**On Ubuntu:**

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0
09:27:05.392576 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.6 tell 192.168.1.7, length 28
09:27:06.392751 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.6 tell 192.168.1.7, length 28
09:27:07.393210 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.6 tell 192.168.1.7, length 28

09:27:18.197496 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.7 tell 192.168.1.6, length 28
09:27:18.198072 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.7 is-at 52:54:00:12:34:56 (oui Unknown), length 28
09:28:19.206009 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.7 tell 192.168.1.6, length 28
09:28:19.206558 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.7 is-at 52:54:00:12:34:56 (oui Unknown), length 28
```

ARP Requests towards 192.168.1.7 are not seen when I connect with Wireshark to WSL interface on Windows.

Can anyone tell what is wrong with this set up and how to make Windows and QEMU see and ping each other? Why I can reach both interfaces (QEMU and Windows) from Ubuntu (WSL2) via bridge interface but ping is not going through?

Comment: Thanks for reposting over here!  I'll see if I can take a look at this, but no promises given the complexity of testing it.  Here's a thought in the meantime, though - It may or may not be applicable to this use-case, but if you are running under Windows 11 with the WSL Preview, you can set the WSL2 interface to bridged.  I think that's ultimately what you are going to need for this, but I'm not certain.  It's probably also possible to accomplish it through some port forwarding -- See my [Option 2 in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403545/1165986) - Would that do it?

Comment: Hyper-V might filter MAC addresses: beside initial's eth0 MAC that has probably been inherited by br0, other MAC addresses might be refused.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks for the hints.
I set WSL virtual interface to "External network" via hyper-v manager - this is what I think is "bridged" version for hyper-v.
I can play around with port forwarding but this has two issues:
1. It will require separate rules for every service I want to use
2. The answer you pointed to is to reach WSL2 from outside world - this I already achieved - what I want is bring QEMU to the world.

Comment: @A.B Sounds like a possibility but can you elaborate? Is this documented anywhere? Is there any way to mitigate this?

Comment: I don't know much about nor use this kind of environment. Here's a random link found on Internet telling it should be possible/configurable (but there was a problem leading to the question asked): https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/8b992d5d-5fd9-4e19-9b5a-83c3f3c7c7d6/nested-vm-doesnt-have-network-conn-despite-of-mac-spoofing-enabled?forum=winserverhyperv

Comment: Thanks for the link. I enabled "MAC Spoofing" on WSL interface but it didn't change anything. I did however take some tcpdump logs and added them to original question - it seem that traffic is blocked in one direction only so MAC blocking might still be a good guess.

Comment: @xJason Sorry, took me a bit to find the link, but see the article linked in [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/swfyf7/bridged_networking_under_wsl_nonkluge/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).  That's the only way that I'm aware of to truly get bridged networking in WSL2.  I haven't tried it myself yet, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot - link looks promising but I only have Windows 10 (corporate so no way to upgrade it myself - added that information to the question) and in the link it states it requires Windows 11. I tried of course to follow the instructions but with completely no effect (WLS2 still uses WSL virtual adapter instead of the one I created). So I think Windows 11 is hard requirement.

Comment: @xJason On at least Windows 11 21H2, it doesn't seem like `Get-VM` even list WSL2 instances. Could you provide some more details on how exactly you enabled MAC Spoofing on "WSL interface"?

Comment: Sure. WSL switch is available under "-ManagementOs" option so I enable it like this:  
`Set-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -Name WSL -MacAddressSpoofing On`.  
There was also another place similar setting existed:  
`$A=Get-VMSystemSwitchExtensionPortFeature -FeatureName "Ethernet Switch Port Security Settings"`  
`$A.SettingData.AllowMacSpoofing = $True`  
`Add-VMSwitchExtensionPortFeature -ExternalPort -SwitchName WSL -VMSwitchExtensionFeature $A`.  
But like I wrote even enabling those in both places at the same time didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @xJason I see. So you were manipulating the switch (port or not), which was more or less what I've guessed. I'm afraid that as of today, there's probably no way to achieve what you want. The problem is that the actual "WSL interface" (that is attached to the switch you were manipulating / shared by all the WSL instances) is not exposed to users like the virtual NIC(s) of Hyper-V VMs. In the case of Hyper-V VM, enabling MacAddressSpoofing on the *VM's virtual NIC* will prevent Ethernet frames with different source MAC being filtered (the option name is actually kind of misleading).

Comment: @xJason If you really need the qemu / inner VM to be in the same IP subnet, my guess is setting up some kind of ARP proxy in the wsl instance might be the only way. There's also `dup` and`fwd` in nftables that might be of your interests.

Comment: @TomYan Thanks for the hint. I tried with all means I could found (proxy_arp, parprouted, ebtables, nftables, arptables) and couldn't make this to work. Maybe this is due to my limited networking knowledge but unless someone can come up with a solution that really works for this set up I will have to consider this as WSL2 limitation and this question as unresolvable.